# Is possible to create a Microsoft Azure function to listen subscription created for particular topic?

Tags: javascript, azure

I am new to Azure console functions. I can able to get the topic messages using ServiceBusTopicTrigger-JavaScript. But I need to create a function which listen, if any subscription is create for a particular topic in console.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no trigger for listening subscription created for a particular topic. You can implement it by yourself. For example, you can create Service Bus queue named `newsubformytoiciscreated` or something else. When a subscription is created for the topic, in the meantime, send a message to the queue. Then create *ServiceBusQueueTrigger-JavaScript* for that queue.

Create a queue:

```
serviceBusService.createQueueIfNotExists('newsubformytoiciscreated', function(error) {
  if(!error) {
    // Queue created
  }
});

function sendMsg(msg, callback) {
  var message = {body: msg};
  serviceBusService.sendQueueMessage('newsubformytoiciscreated', message, callback);
}
```

Create a subscription:

```
serviceBusService.createSubscription('mytopic', 'Sub1', function(error) {
  if(!error) {
    // subscription created
    sendMsg('Subscription created for mytopic.', function(err) {
      if(!err) // message sent.
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Aaron Chen - MSFT, Is there any Java API to create Azure functions dynamically?. for ex. Creating ServiceBusQueueTrigger-JavaScript in using java SDK and it is showing in the function list.

Comment: Hi Ram, there is a way to create Azure function dynamically by using ARM Template. You can refer to [this post](https://cmatskas.com/deploying-azure-functions-with-arm-templates-and-the-kudu-rest-api/) for more information.